# Workqueue handling if the same interrupt occurs before workqueue finishes

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, workqueue

In Linux,I have an ISR and I want to schedule a workqueue to push my work to bottom half. Now I have a situation where the workqueue has not finished its task and the same interrupt occurs again.

Now how should I handle the situation or rather is there something need to be done to handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

The same work cannot be scheduled again. so the workqueue is checked for pending work and the new work is discarded if old is not completed. This is the default behaviour